# repo init connection times out

Tags: android, android-source, cyanogenmod

I was trying to download the source code for Android, CyanogenMod in order to learn more about customizing Android ROMs, I'm on fresh installed Linux Mint 11, and I've set up everything correctly. Now, when I tried to pull from github using repo:

```
$ repo init -u http://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git
```

I get the following error message:

> Getting repo ...
>   from git://android.git.kernel.org/tools/repo.git android.git.kernel.org[0: 92.242.132.18]: errno=Connection timed out
>   fatal: unable to connect a socket (Connection timed out)

Google search found this answer that it is a firewall issue, that the system cannot connect to android.git.kernel.org on port 9418. (I've tried downloading the Android AOSP source as well). However, there's no answer on what to do to enable the system to connect to port 9418. Please let me know, I'm a noob on Linux as well.

Comment: git clone http://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git works for me

Answer (score 0):

`kernel.org` has been recently hacked. It is still not back. http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/09/05/kernel-org-hacked-how-to-get-android-repo/

Answer (score 0):

The script repo and the android kernel source have moved to google.
http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here. It turned out that the tool repo was outdated. I did notice this fact because I had two versions of this file on my disk. I asked the system how it links to the command `repo`.

`$ which repo`

`~/bin/repo`

After copying the new repo script to this location, the error was gone.